# mips finding offset in beq instruction

Tags: mips32

I am new to MIPS - 32 and I have problem understanding the offset of the following instruction:

```
beq $a0,$a1,0x00401200
```

knowing that

```
PC=0x0040122C
```

I think that

```
$a0=00100
$a1=00101
```

the instruction should be 000100|00100|00101|0001 0010 0000 0000.

the solution says the offset is -12, but I do not understand why.
Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: If that instruction at 0x40122C did not branch, the next instruction would be fetched from 0x401230.  To branch to 0x401200 instead is a difference of -0x30, or -48 in decimal.  The offset actually encoded into the instruction is 1/4 of this, because all instructions are 4 bytes long and it's meaningless to jump into the middle of an instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The target address is found by `TA = PC + 4(offset)`

So the `offset = (TA - PC)/4`

0x00401200 is your target address. We see that it is going backwards, so we must make sure our answer is negative. In this case, I prefer to do PC - TA and then find the 2s complement.

`PC - TA :  0x0040122C - 0x00401200 = 0x002C`

We can find the 2s complement by doing

`0xFFFF(16)-0x002C = 0xFFFD4`

Now we can divide by 4 to find the TA by doing a right shift 2 places

`1111 1111 1111 1101 0100 -> 11 1111 1111 1111 0101
The offset = 0xFFF5`

I ended up with the offset = -11 (0xFFF5). However, if I plug that back into 
TA = PC + 4(offset),  I get 0x401200.